# Dynamic parameters in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a `LINETYPE` parameter with the following values:

```
    INV_DEVICE
    INV_SIM
    TAX
    OTHER_ITEMS
```

If the user chooses anything from the `LINETYPE` parameter anything that start with "`INV_*`", is it possible that another parameter field be populated dynamically?

For example, the user chooses `INV_DEVICE`. There would appear another parameter field called `GOODSTYPE`.
Values for `GOODSTYPE` are taken from the database. Example:

```
    PAGER
    GSMPHONE
    SMARTPHONE
    TABLET
```

But when the user chooses `TAX` or `OTHER_ITEMS` the user does not need to choose any value from `GOODSTYPE`, or the parameter field does not show at all.

The output of the report are those matching the criteria the user entered.
Note that for `LINETYPE` and `GOODSTYPE`, user can choose multiple values.
LINETYPE is a mandatory field, but `GOODSTYPE` will vary upon the values chosen by the user in `LINETYPE`

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is call Cascading Parameters.  The first selection leads to a refined list on the second selection which leads to another refined list, etc.  Like Country -> State/Province -> City.

I don't use it but from what I gather, your selection needs to be stored in a table.  To create a Cascading Parameter:

1. Create a new parameter
2. Under List of Values, select Dynamic
3. Select your value, description and Paramter
4. Set the option for Allow Multiple Values
5. repeat step 3-4 if you have more parameters.